# MMSE Art Gallery

Tags: discussion

Similar to [Journal of the Matter Modeling Stack Exchange](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/329/5), we have had some great pictures posted on this site. Here's an appreciation thread for all the beautiful pictures!

Answer (score 1):

**German Barcenas (2022) [Units of SASA generated from GROMACS gmx_sasa?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8832/5)**

[image: Molecules analyzed by gmx SASA]

Answer (score 1):

This is a community Wiki answer, so please feel free to add more pictures by editing this answer. The ordering is based on the year that the image was added.

---

ChengCheng Xiao (2023)

[Can you calculate fat ("projected") phonon dispersion bands with Quantum Espresso?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10926/6687)

[image: Fat Phonon Bands]

---

Vandan Revanur (2023)

[Pymol_electrostatic_interactions](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10483/6687)

[image]

---

Abd-Elazeem Mohamed (2022)

[Parameterising a Lennard-Jones interaction: Which atoms should I scan to build potential energy surface?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8921/parameterising-a-lennard-jones-interaction-which-atoms-should-i-scan-to-build-p)
[image]

---

Newbite Quantum Chemist (2022)

[CrysX](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10040/6687)

[image] [image]

---

Mykd (2022)

[What are some recent significant developments/studies in theoretical nonlinear chemical dynamics?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8812/6687)
[image]

---

Sak (2022)

[MultiWfn](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10049/6687)
[image]

---

Xing (2021)

[Beautiful Atoms](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/7063/6687)
[image]

---

Hebo (2021)

[Pymol](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/7207/6687)
[image]

---

Alessio Valentini (2021)

[Blender](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4519/6687)

[image]

---

Water Molecule (2021)

[VMD](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4513/6687)

[image]

---

Hebo (2021)

[UnityMol](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/6731/6687)
[image]

---

High Performance Rangsiman (2021)

[Molview](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/6731/6687)
[image]

---

Littleworth (2021)

[Pymol Lysine](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6987/6687)
[image]

---

Cody Aldaz (2021)

[Adobe Dimension](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4516/6687)

[image]

---

Stephane Redon (2021)

[Samson](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4523/6687)

[image]

---

Leopold (2021)

[iRaspa](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/5059/6687)
[image]

---

Tristan Maxson (2021)

[Multiwfn](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/2286/6687)

[image]

---

Camps (2020)

[Mercury](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1928/6687)
[image]

---

Marcin (2020)

[AtomEye](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/472/6687)

[image]

---

Comment: I like the figure at the end of this answer: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10926/5

Comment: Added the image.